# Hidden input gets wrong ID

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php scripts whit a table thats sorts after time.
in that table i have a check box to mark if somthings is deleverd and i have a hidden input thats get the id. it worked yesterday but know it gets the id lowest on the table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bestalning` WHERE lev=0
ORDER BY tid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
echo "<form method='POST' action='ID_change.php'>";
echo "<div class='continer bg-vit table-rsponsive-sm '><table class='table'><thead class='thead-dark'>
<tr><th >".'Lev'."</th><th>".' '."</th><th >".'Artikelnr'."</th><th >".'Antal'."</th>
<th >".'Singnatur'."</th><th >".'Önskad ankomst'."</th><th >".'Skickad'."</th></tr></thead></div>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tbody><tr><td><input style='margin-right:5px;' name='levJA' type='checkbox' value='1'></td><td>
    <input style='margin-right:5px;' name='RowID' type='hidden' value='".$row['ID']."'></td><td>".$row['artikelnr']."</td>
    <td>".$row['antal']."</td><td>".$row['ovrigt']."</td><td>".$row['Tid']."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td></tr></tbody>"; 
}
echo " <input class='btn btn-dark m-1' type='submit' value='submit'></form>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

ID_change.php

```
  $Lev = $_POST['levJA'];
$ID = $_POST['RowID'];

$sql = "UPDATE bestalning SET lev='".$Lev."' WHERE ID='".$ID."'";
echo $sql;
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql,)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple results or just one?

Comment: @Qirel if you mean row then yes if you mean in the sql query then no

Comment: So `mysqli_fetch_array()` only iterates once?

Comment: @Qirel im not the best at english do you mean if it runs more then once?

Comment: Yes, does the result from the query return more than 1 row? To find out, you can do `echo "Rows returned: ".$result->num_rows;` before your loop.

Comment: @Qirel yeah i have more then 1 row. But i tride to run the ID_change and it just selected the higest ID whitout needing to select one.

Comment: Exactly what I were getting at - if there are multiple rows, only the last `name` attribute will holds its value. You might want one form for each row instead, or by using arrays.

Comment: @Qirel do i need to move the submit in to the loop too?